# What is the right way to consistently mangle bash terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm on OSX 10.11.1 and occasionally my bash terminal gets mangled. It often happens when I accidentally `cat` a binary file. The result can be seen on the image below. The output becomes weird, and I can't type ascii characters anymore.

[image]

Even though this happens occasionally, I couldn't find a way to consistently reproduce the issue. Online search recommends doing `cat /bin/*`, but that works sporadically, only after a couple dozen tries.

I want to do this so I can find an easy solution how to handle this in `tmux`.

How do I consistently get bash to a "mangled" state? Is there maybe a magic unicode character that can do this?

Comment: Just echo control characters.

Comment: Why do you think you need to reproduce this to "handle" it? Just run `reset`  as necessary.

Comment: By the way, it's not bash that's in a mangled state, it's the terminal; see [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/80216)  (OK, yes, the fact that you're asking for a bash command is marginally relevant — but only marginally.)

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506123/5132 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like the [DEC special graphics character set](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/table2-4.html).

Reading the [xterm control sequences docs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Controls-beginning-with-ESC), it sounds like the terminal uses those when receiving `ESC` `(` `0`.

So you should be able to reproduce using

```
printf '\033(0'
```

or

```
printf '\033(0' > corrupt-my-terminal
cat corrupt-my-terminal
```

And get back using

```
printf '\033(B'
```

which according to the same page selects USASCII.

---

Other ways to restore the state include

```
tput sgr0  # resets all terminal attributes to their defaults
```

and

```
reset      # reinitializes the terminal
```

You could `tput sgr0` in your `PROMPT_COMMAND` (bash), or `precmd` (zsh) to ensure it always gets reset automatically.

---

Or you could just make sure to use `less`, `vim`, or anything other than `cat` to view a file.

To make `less` act like `cat` and automatically quit if the file is under one page long, run `less -FX`, or do `export LESS=-FX`.

Or if you don't want to always use those `less` options, make a new alias, e.g.

```
alias c='less -FX'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect answer and just what I was looking for. With `printf '\033(0'` command I can consistently get the terminal in the "mangled" state.

Comment: Instead of using `PROMPT_COMMAND` in Bash, you could prepend the output of `tput sgr0` to your `PS1` (e.g. `PS1="$(tput sgr0)$PS1"`) - saving a process every time you see the prompt.

Comment: I think I also messed up with that exact DEC character set. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454590/pc-speaker-beep-and-messy-terminal-font-due-to-dd-if-dev-sda?noredirect=1#comment826232_454590 .

Answer (score 2):

The most common way for the graphics character set in a VT100 emulator to get selected accidentally is by receiving a <kbd>Control-N</kbd> character, also known as shift-out. If you cat a binary file and there's a byte in it with the value '\14', that can cause the terminal emulator to shift to the graphics character set. It is undone upon receiving a <kbd>Control-O</kbd> character, shift-in (or by a control sequence that resets the terminal). It is independent of bash or any other shell that may be running in the terminal emulator.

For a terminal emulator running inside a terminal emulator, the semantics can be a bit complex. For instance, here is how [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Window-Termcap.html) handles it:

> When the boolean ‘G0’ capability is present in the termcap entry for the terminal on which screen has been called, the terminal emulation of screen supports multiple character sets. This allows an application to make use of, for instance, the VT100 graphics character set or national character sets. The following control functions from ISO 2022 are supported: ‘lock shift G0’ (‘SI’), ‘lock shift G1’ (‘SO’), ‘lock shift G2’, ‘lock shift G3’, ‘single shift G2’, and ‘single shift G3’. When a virtual terminal is created or reset, the ASCII character set is designated as ‘G0’ through ‘G3’. When the ‘G0’ capability is present, screen evaluates the capabilities ‘S0’, ‘E0’, and ‘C0’ if present. ‘S0’ is the sequence the terminal uses to enable and start the graphics character set rather than ‘SI’. ‘E0’ is the corresponding replacement for ‘SO’. ‘C0’ gives a character by character translation string that is used during semi-graphics mode.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar scenario using Bitvise SSH Client neither `reset` nor `tput sgr0` worked for me to restore the terminal back to normal display.

After some research I pinpointed the offending character to `0x0E` (`SHIFT OUT`):

[image]

I was able to unmangle it by blindly echoing `0x0F` (`SHIFT IN`):

```
echo -e '\x0f'
```