# How is printing a binary in my terminal changing the character mapping?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

I accidentally ran `cat` on a binary.  (It happens).
Usually, I witness a flood of random unicode characters in which I hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.
Sometimes I hear random bell noises because the file has `'\'` `'a'` characters next to each other.

This time, it changed my entire character mapping (I think):
(image shows part of a `cat`'d file before hitting ctrl+C and typing `ls`)
[image]

The problem is easily fixed, but I'm left wondering what caused this.
What can I type into my terminal to produce the same effect?

If relevant, I'm using `gnome-terminal` and my shell is `zsh`.

Comment: [An excellent explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246060)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a terminal escape sequence; you could extract those and print them one-by-one to see if a particular sequence causes the borkage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# turn off any encoding foo
use open IO => ':raw';

# "slurp" mode for whole file reads
local $/;

# for any STDIN or files given to us...
while (readline) {
    # extract ESC-followed by a number of not-ESC not-NUL characters...
    while (m/(\e[^\e\0]+)/g) {
        printf "what does '%vx' do?\n", $1;
        print $1;
        # is a listing borked or not?
        print qx(ls);
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```