# Control characters in bash history scramble subsequent lines

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history, control-characters

Sometimes, when I invoke `history` in bash, it starts printing normally, and at some point switches to garbled characters:

[image: history screenshot]

Oddly, when I copy that from my terminal and paste it here, the characters are different:

```
19955  ssh somehost-bacc
19956  ssh-keygen -R somehost-bacc
19957  ssh somehost-bacc
19958  ssh otherhost-bacc
19959  

19960  __h +_+-+e_+-bacc
19961  d_y +_+-+e_+-bacc
19962  dia+--b _bc+c-_dc-2-c+c
19963  d_y _bc+c-_dc-2-c+c
```

My prompt and everything are garbled after that, until I `reset`.

Looking around in .bash_history in Vim or less, that line shows as `^L^N^U`. I definitely didn't just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> at the prompt then.

The first time this happened, I deleted that line, and `history` printed normally afterward.
This is the second time it's happened, and I want to know why, and how to avoid it.

Context:
Bash 4.2.46(2)-release on CentOS 7.7.1908
SecureCRT 8.3.4 on Windows 10 1909

Comment: In SecureCRT, I have Terminal emulation: XTerm; Character encoding: UTF-8. If I change Terminal to ANSI, it fixes this problem, but the appearance of Vim is all screwed up.

Comment: There's an explanation of the terminal behaviour at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506140/5132 , so I am assuming that _this_ question is asking how those control characters keep getting into your shell's command history.

Comment: Yes, I mostly want to know how it happened and how to stop it. (I am curious about the mechanism, but I'm not sure I want to go farther down that rabbit hole than “bad characters make text go oopsie.”)

Comment: `stty reset` will fix it. You have sent your terminal ASCII Control Characters   including ^N and ^O. See http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php